# Request Keys of value that is not an object in React native listview while fetching json from api?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This may be dumb question but as a beginner am struggling with this don't know where am making mistake when am trying to fetch jsonarray value from api am getting Requested keys of a value that is not an object don't know where am making mistake now let me post what i have tried so far
this is the index.android code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  ListView,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';
var REQUEST_URL = 'http://someurl';

var AwesomeProject = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },

  fetchData: function() {
    fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.movies),
          loaded: true,
        });
      })
      .done();
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView();
    }

    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderMovie}
        style={styles.listView}
      />
    );
  },

  renderLoadingView: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Loading movies...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  },

  renderMovie: function(movie) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.HeaderText}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.SubText}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  rightContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 8,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  year: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    width: 53,
    height: 81,
  },
  listView: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

This is the response am getting from api :

```
 [{"HeaderText":"Contract Approval","ApprovalType":"C","ApprovalCount":0,"SubText":"New / Change","ApproverID":198},{"HeaderText":"Contract Specification Approval","ApprovalType":"CS","ApprovalCount":0,"SubText":"New / Change","ApproverID":198},{"HeaderText":"Spare Part Request Approval","ApprovalType":"SPR","ApprovalCount":0,"SubText":"New / Change","ApproverID":198},{"HeaderText":"Spare Part Non Return Approval","ApprovalType":"SPNR","ApprovalCount":0,"SubText":"New / Change","ApproverID":198},{"HeaderText":"Spare Purchase Request Approval","ApprovalType":"SPRA","ApprovalCount":0,"SubText":"New / Change","ApproverID":198},{"HeaderText":"Spare Request Approval","ApprovalType":"SSRA","ApprovalCount":0,"SubText":"New / Change","ApproverID":198}]
```

Getting requested keys of a value that is not an object can anyone help me am struggling with this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you mixing my example json with yours....for your case just use `responseData` instead of `responseData.movies`

Comment: Thank you man you are genius as a beginner am struggling bit